# Very slow MySQL subquery

Tags: mysql

I have two tables that each contain about 500 customer data records. Each record in each of the tables has an email field. Sometimes the same email addresses exist on both tables, sometimes not. I want to retrieve every email address on table1 that doesn't exist on table2. The email field in each table is indexed. I'm doing the select with a sub query that is really slow, 10 to 20 seconds.

```
select email
from
t1
where
email not in (select email from t2)
```

There's actually about 30K rows in each table, but I can knock it down to 500 each very quickly with an additional 'where' to filter by category. It's only when I add that subquery that it slows down dramatically. So, I am sure this can be faster, and I know a join should be much faster than the subquery, but can't figure out how to do that. I found a left outer join explanation here on SO, that looked like it should help, but got nowhere with it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you create any index?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

mysql does not optimize a subquery in the WHERE clause (edit: it re-runs the subquery for every row tested)

to convert to a JOIN, try something like

```
SELECT email FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON (t1.email = t2.email)
WHERE t2.email IS NULL
```

this should run very fast, a covering index query.
The query optimizer should walk the email index of t1, check the
email index of t2, and output those emails that are in t1 but not in t2.

Edit: I should add, mysql *does* optimize a subquery in the JOIN clause: it runs the subquery and puts the results into a "derived table" (temporary table without any indexes), and joins the derived table like any other.  The syntax is a bit funny, each derived table must have an alias, ie `... JOIN (SELECT ...) AS derived ON ...`.

Comment: Sweet. Thank you. .046 query time.

Comment: excellent!  I edited my answer to add more details of how mysql optimizes subquries (the versions of mysql I've used, at any rate)

Answer (score 2):

Usually subqueries do more processing than usual query. In your case it first fetches all the emails from t2 and compares it with the email list of t1.

You can try like below, without using a sub query.

```
SELECT email FROM t1,t2 WHERE t1.email!=t2.email
```

Comment: if it did that, it would run fast, because t1.email is indexed (you're describing joining derived tables; fetching all the emails and comparing them to the email list of t1 is what a `(SELECT email FROM t2) AS tmp JOIN t1` does).  The reason this query slow is because the where clause is evaluated once for each email from t1, and this runs the subquery each time, and each result set is then linear-searched for an IN match (linear search because subquery results do not have indexes).

Answer (score 1):

The best way to improve the performance of `SELECT` operations is to create indexes on one or more of the columns that are tested in the query. The index entries act like pointers to the table rows, allowing the query to quickly determine which rows match a condition in the `WHERE` clause, and retrieve the other column values for those rows. All MySQL data types can be indexed.

some tricks for creating mysql tables ..
[see this.](http://www.ajaxline.com/32-tips-to-speed-up-your-mysql-queries)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work fine

```
SELECT email from T1
LEFT JOIN T2
ON T1.email=T2.email
WHERE T2.email!=NULL
```

Comment: NULL must be tested for with `IS` or `IS NOT`, the comparison operators =, <>, <, >, != will all return false when comparing against NULL